# How to unarchive an rkv file?

Tags: archiving, file-archiver

I have an `.rkv` archive file from the early 2000's that I would like to unarchive.

I found a [github script](https://github.com/mwoehlke/unrkv), but using that it tells me:

```
IOError: not an RKV archive
```

Using the unix command `file` it simply says the file is "data".

I also found a dos program on [this website](http://www.dcee.net/Files/Archiver/), which I was able to run through dosbox, but the program appears to be too old for the file, saying:

```
Processing archive file archive.rkv
 ERROR: Incompatible version: v5.2 is required to read archive.rkv
```

Any idea how I can unarchive this file?

Comment: You could examine the start of the file with `head -n1 thefilename.rkv`, which might give us a clue.

Comment: @AndrewMorton `head` is designed for text and it will probably print some binary "garbage" the OP cannot post easily. I would go with `hexdump -C thefilename.fkv | head -n 8` or so.